# Confusion about NTFS compression and `du` on ZFS (was: How to *really* disable NTFS compression?)

Tags: zfs, qemu, ntfs, compression

I am using ZFS with compression+dedup on my host system and use Qemu/KVM for virtualization. I wanted to let ZFS do it's job and disable Windows 10's NTFS compression feature (both, CompactOS and NTFS FS compression). However, things didn't work as expected, so I did some more testing as shown below.

**TL;DR** How can NTFS compression *really* be disabled? Windows seems to ignore settings and GPO.... o.O

***It turns out, there was no issue but just confusion about `du`'s output on ZFS systems.*** See accepted answer.

## Test

### 1 Disable compression

1. `fsutil behavior set disablecompression 1`
2. `compact /compactos:never` (this shouldn't affect this test, but let's disable it anyways)
3. Set "do not allow compression on NTFS volumes" via GPO
4. reboot

### 2 Create test data

uncompressable:

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=uncomp.bin bs=1M count=5500
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=uncomp2.bin bs=1M count=3000
# I had Ctrl-C'ed somewhere so I finally ended up with these sizes:
# du -scm uncomp*
2861    uncomp2.bin
3642    uncomp.bin
6503    total
# check
$ tar -cf - uncomp* | lz4 >uncomp.comp
$ du -m uncomp.comp
6503    uncomp.comp
```

and compressable:

```
$ lzdgen -o comp -r 3.0 -s 6503m
# check
$ cat comp | lz4 >comp.comp
$ du -h comp.comp
2,2G    comp.comp
```

### 3 Create raw test disks

```
$ qemu-img create -f raw testdisk1.img 10G
$ qemu-img create -f raw testdisk.img 10G
```

Attached both disks via VirtIO to the Windows VM, initialized and formatted them as NTFS volumes.

### 4 Copy test data to test disk

Copy `uncomp*` to `testdisk` and `comp` to `testdisk1` and check disk usage.

[image: testdisk]
[image: testdisk]

Both volumes show the same disk usage, as expected.

### 5 Check raw disk image sizes

With NTFS compression being disabled I would expect the two raw disk images having exactly the same size, however, the (compressable) data still gets compressed:

```
$ du -h testdisk*
2,2G    testdisk1.img
6,4G    testdisk.img

$ qemu-img info testdisk.img 
image: testdisk.img
file format: raw
virtual size: 10 GiB (10737418240 bytes)
disk size: 6.35 GiB

$ qemu-img info testdisk1.img 
image: testdisk1.img
file format: raw
virtual size: 10 GiB (10737418240 bytes)
disk size: 2.17 GiB
```

### 6 Check data size of testdisk1 when mounted

Just to be sure ...

```
$ sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 testdisk1.img
$ mkdir /tmp/mnt
$ sudo mount /dev/nbd0p2 /tmp/mnt
$ df -h
...
/dev/nbd0p2                               10G  6,4G  3,6G  64% /tmp/mnt
$ du -sch /tmp/mnt
6,4G    /tmp/mnt
6,4G    total
```

## Update 1

After verifying `testdisk1` (thanks for the hint @DanielB!), I realized that `lzdgen` creates nullbyte-holes, which is pretty bad for testing. Thus, I've redone the test using a file created this way:

```
./fio --name=randomwrite --ioengine=sync --rw=readwrite --bs=4k --size=5600M --buffer_compress_percentage=50 --refill_buffers --buffer_pattern=0xdeadbeef --filename=comp2
```

Instead of nullbyte-holes, the pattern 0xdeadbeef is used. The file is perfectly compressable:

```
$du -h comp2
5,5G    comp2
$ cat comp2 | lz4 >yyy
$ du -h yyy
2,8G    yyy
```

After copying the file `comp2` to the (freshly recreated) `testdisk1`, the raw image looks like that:

```
$ du -h testdisk1.img 
3,0G    testdisk1.img
```

Using hexedit I searched for the beginning of the file and dumped it using dd:

```
dd if=testdisk1.img of=comp2_dump skip=3367040 bs=1k count=5734400
5734400+0 records in
5734400+0 records out
5872025600 bytes (5,9 GB, 5,5 GiB) copied, 48,2982 s, 122 MB/s
c0d3@z3r0:[~]# du -sch comp2_dump
3,0G    comp2_dump
3,0G    total
$ sha1sum comp2_dump comp2 
22171686b58536d50c8b516ee859213650cb6b55  comp2_dump
22171686b58536d50c8b516ee859213650cb6b55  comp2
```

Wat....

Comment: remind, that a file that has been already flagged for compressed with ntfs, will stay compacted

Comment: NTFS compression (not specific to Windows 10 btw) is not magically active, _especially_ on files the user creates. It is an attribute that you must manually enable on files. So don’t guess whether the files are compressed or not, check.

Comment: @djdomi the files are not flagged, as they were created freshly, as you can see ;)

Comment: @DanielB Ok, checked and found out two things: a) lzdgen uses holes which is pretty bad for testing, so I've tested again with fio generating non-zero holes (0xdeadbeef instead) b) even though the file gets written to the disk as-is (non-compressed!) and I can extract it from `testdisk1` without decompression, `du` shows 3.0G.... weird

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I finally found out what's going on here. `du` seems to show the compressed/deduped size (ZFS). I've copied the file `comp2` to a zfs dataset without compression/dedup and `du` shows the correct 5,5G:

```
$ sudo zfs create -o mountpoint=/wtf rpool/zroot/wtf
$ sudo cp comp2 /wtf/
$ zfs list rpool/zroot/wtf
NAME              USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool/zroot/wtf  5.47G   224G     5.47G  /wtf
$ du -h /wtf/comp2 
5,5G    /wtf/comp2
```

The same happens with `testdisk1`:

```
$ sudo rm /wtf/comp2
$ sudo cp testdisk1.img /wtf/
$ zfs list rpool/zroot/wtf
NAME              USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool/zroot/wtf  5.49G   224G     5.49G  /wtf
$ du -h /wtf/testdisk1.img
5,5G    /wtf/testdisk1.img
```

Comment: Now edit question and accept answer so it makes sense and is useful to others.